# Partitioning an array

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm struggling with writing an algorithm for converting an array to all possible permutations of that array but they have to be inline/consecutive. Example below:

Array:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

The results would be:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
...
```

`Array#permutations` creates permutations but they are not in order.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by term "order"? And what is your desired order?

Comment: Are you looking for permutations or not?

Comment: I use the term "permutations" but I may be misusing it. `Array#permutations` gives ALL the possible permutations. What I'm looking for is all the possible ARRAY "permutations" as the output suggests.

Comment: Your output is not permutation. It is partition.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk please be clear of what operation you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "operation" is called. I think I would probably figure it out if I knew the algorithm. I provided an example to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
(0...a.length)
.flat_map{|i| (1...a.length).to_a.combination(i).to_a}
.map{|cut| i = -1; a.slice_before{cut.include?(i +=1)}.to_a}
```

Comment: As you probably already have figured out, I focused on the indices, while you focused on the length. They are interesting ways to go.

Comment: Wow, I spent one hour yesterday trying to figure out a simple solution like this one.

Comment: @sawa Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't figure out how to do it. Jeffrey I probably spent more time than you :)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question (and this is differently from how others have understood it), you want every possible grouping (partitioning) of the array where the individual elements of the array (the characters) maintain their order (always `'a'`, then `'b'`, then `'c'`, ... `'f'`).  I saw this as a matter of getting the set of ordered lists of the size of each partition.

That is, I represent your three example partitionings first as:

```
[[1, 5],
 [2, 4],
 [2, 2, 2],
 ...]
```

So I first generate:

```
[[6], [1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3] ...]
```

and then use that to generate the final result.

The way I generate the sizes is wildly inefficient.  It's the first thing that came to mind, and it works fine for your array, but a better algorithm would be necessary if it's going to need to handle larger arrays.  (And sawa has now provided a shorter, more efficient solution.)

```
def sizes(n)
  (1..n).each_with_object([]) do |i, sizes|
    sizes.concat (1..n).to_a.repeated_permutation(i).select{|a| a.reduce(:+) == n}
  end
end

def partitions_of(a)
  sizes(a.size).each_with_object([]) do |sizes, results|
    dup = a.dup
    results << sizes.each_with_object([]) do |size, result|
      result << dup.shift(size)
    end
  end
end
```

Using your array, this:

```
partitions_of(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

produces this:

```
[[["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c", "d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b", "c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e", "f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d", "e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c", "d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a", "b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]],
 [["a"], ["b"], ["c"], ["d"], ["e"], ["f"]]]
```

Which, if I understand correctly, is exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all possible combinations of all possible permutations of the array, then you generate the permutations and then generate slices of them:

```
array = %w(a b c d e f)
r = array.permutation(array.length).map {|perm|
  perm.length.times.map {|i| perm.each_slice(i+1).to_a }
}.flatten(1)
```

This will generate every possible grouping of every possible permutation of the input array. I'm not quite sure that's what you're looking for, though.

Comment: This will generate all possible orders of the permutations as well.

Comment: Yup. I elected for that since it covers *all* the cases, and the desired output set of the original question is unclear. :D

Comment: This is awfully difficult if you don't want ordered repetitions. I've been struggling for about half an hour.

Comment: This works but I'll give credit to @sawa since his solution is faster.